# how to get a value out of a ColdFusion struct object

Tags: pdf, struct, coldfusion

I am creating a pdf document (via ColdFusion), and rendering the pdf in a browser. The pdf form is already created and I am prefilling and populating the fields.

So what I am doing is dumping the variables out from the pdf to use as the name in a cfpdfformparam. (to get the variables) Then what I am doing is creating  where owner email is the name of the variable from the pdf and then for the value I am assigning the session variable from another form. So that what they have entered prefills in the form they need to fill out. So really name decides the location on the pdf and value is the session variable of what was entered on the other form.

The issue I am having is that the variables that were already created, a few of them have `structs` inside of the variables so I am not sure how to call them in (name portion) in order to prefill and populate the information.

For example how would I prefill in the information for FEID/DL/DMVacct and for FL reg when they contain a struct within the variable?:

like this?: 
`<cfpdfformparam 
name="FEID/DL/DMVacct##" 
value="#session.checkout.info.driverlicense_1#">`

```
<cfpdfform action="read" source="82040y.pdf" result="data" />
<cfdump var="#data#" />
```

[image]
[image]

I am pre-populating the pdf form fields (via ColdFusion session variables), and then rendering the pdf using the following markup:

```
<cfpdfform source="82040.pdf" action="populate">
  <cfpdfformparam name="org" value="">
</cfpdfform>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can access variables embedded inside a struct like this:

```
<!--- using dot notation --->
<cfif StructKeyExists(myStruct, "myKey")>
    <cfoutput> #mystruct.myKey#</cfoutput><br>
</cfif>

<!--- or using access notation --->
<cfif StructKeyExists(myStruct, LastName)>
    <cfoutput>#LastName#: #mystruct[LastName]#</cfoutput><br>
</cfif>
```

You can use `IsDefined` to see if a value exists:

```
IsDefined("structure_name.key")>
```

**However, if the key is dynamic, or contains special characters, you must use the `StructKeyExists` function.**

> **NOTE:** You must be careful about your variable names in ColdFusion. Some of the names assigned to your struct values would be considered invalid if used as variable names. So if your struct names contain invalid characters, you will need to access them via access-notation in order to retrieve them:

```
<!--- use access-notation for value names with special chars --->
data["FEID/DL/DMVacct"]["#"]
```

Otherwise, you will have runtime errors if you attempt dot-notation:

```
<!--- Invalid markup! Don't do this! --->
#data.FEID/DL/DMVacct.##
```

**So here are some examples of how you could access your data:**

```
<!--- Output the value --->
<cfoutput> #data["FEID/DL/DMVacct"]["#"]#</cfoutput><br>

<!--- Storing the value in a variable named 'myVar' --->
<cfset myVar = #data["FEID/DL/DMVacct"]["#"]# />
<cfoutput>#myVar#</cfoutput>
```

If your struct names follow ColdFusion's [variable naming rules](http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Variables_03.html), then you can also access your data with dot-notation, notice I changed the value names `FEID/DL/DMVacct` and `#` to valid variable names: `FEID_DL_DMVacct` and `num`:

```
<!--- Output the value via dot-notation --->
<cfoutput> #data.FEID_DL_DMVacct.num#</cfoutput><br>

<!--- Storing the value in a variable named 'myVar' --->
<cfset myVar = #data.FEID_DL_DMVacct.num# />
<cfoutput>#myVar#</cfoutput>
```

**Hope this helps!**

Comment: Vicki - IMO, the title of your question led folks down the wrong path ;-) Sounds like your real goal was to *populate* a pdf form field - not *get* values from a structure. (While structKeyExists is a reasonable answer to the question asked, it has nothing to do with populating form fields). So can you explain what you actually end up doing to get the field populated?

Comment: *variable names must follow these rules...* That is no longer true. Variables names can be just about anything you want, using associative array notation. Those old rules only apply when using dot notation. (That said, the initial question was misleading. The issue has nothing to do with CF *variable* names - it is about pdf *form field* names.)

Comment: @Leigh, the variable [naming rules for ColdFusion 9](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7fd3.html) seem to be the same as the [naming rules for ColdFusion 8](http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Variables_03.html), but I get what you are saying about accessing values via access notation `[""]` where the rules are slightly different, but the OP wasn't clear about how these values were being used, and invalid variable names could have messed her up down the line.

Comment: However, I completely agree that this question had far more to do with how to get values into a dynamic-PDF and less about getting values out of a struct, so my answer tried to stay relevant to the actual question, while adding bonus ideas to help with her pdf stuff, which was what she was really after.

Comment: And I should add, that I was personally getting errors when trying to access struct values with forward-slashes in them (using access-notation or dot-notation), perhaps it was a version issue (CF 8 vs. CF 9? - not really sure) but when I switched the forward slashes to underscores, it all worked great. So my reasoning was to get her to follow conventions, and that way her variable names will work everywhere (in the pdf, access-notation, dot-notation and anywhere in her CF markup), which results cleaner, less problematic code, and will work no matter the version of CF she is using. win-win-win!

Comment: Yes, but your comment that *"SOME OF YOUR STRUCTS HAVE INVALID VARIABLE NAMES"* is inaccurate. When using structures, the key "FEID/DL/DMVacct.##" is perfectly valid. Since technically it is a structure "key", not a variable name per se, the "variable name rules" do not apply (ignoring bugs). BTW, those rules were more relevant back in the CF3/4days before most scopes were structures. So dot notation was the only way to access certain values. Some functions still rely on dot notation, but overall it is less of an issue these days.

Comment: *getting errors when trying to access struct values with forward-slashes in them* It works fine in CF9/10. Maybe you encountered a different issue.

Comment: @Leigh, I see what you are saying. I have changed the language in my answer to be less verbose, and assuming. These comments will be good for the OP to learn from though.

Comment: Still getting the error when trying to parse struct values with forward-slashes, but that just might be my environment (and not a problem I care to solve, ATM), but my coding-style enforces strict naming conventions, so if it's under my control, I would never voluntarily assign a data value with a forward slash or a pound sign in the name. Just a personal preference (and convention for most languages).

Comment: ... or how the code is doing the parsing. Though I cannot see why it would cause an issue. Not unless the code is doing something weird, like using evaluate(). RE: Naming conventions, what is "advisable" is a different conversation than what is "syntactically valid". But I agree on avoiding exotic names when possible. Unfortunately, not everyone shares the sentiment: case in point - the form at hand ;-)

Comment: *Naming conventions, what is "advisable" is a different conversation than what is "syntactically valid". But I agree on avoiding exotic names when possible. Unfortunately, not everyone shares the sentiment: case in point - the form at hand ;-)* -- **100% AGREED! =)**

Answer (score 6):

```
structName['FEID/DL/DMVacct']['##'] = variable
```

You need the double `#` to escape them and produce one singular `#`